# UX/UI design - boot-camp or self teach

Tags: interaction-design

How to start UX design? Should I attend a boot-camp or self-teach? If self-teach, what are some good resources out there for me to use?

Answer (score 1):

For me, if you will be starting out for UX Design, read Steve Krug's [Don't Make Me Think, Revisited](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321965515) for Web Usability.

If you are targeting Windows Forms, Microsoft has its free documentation UX Guide for [Windows Forms](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4249) and [Windows Store](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30704).

References on usability is a good keyword for you to start your own adventure of searching for good references. I do believe that when you use "right keywords", you get "right results".

The best of all I have mentioned is learning thru experience. If you have already made different software projects, then re-create them with the thinking of improving its user experience, or simply place yourself in the shoes of the users. Have your friends crticize your own UX.

Hope this helps. Good luck~!

Answer (score 0):

"Practice make man perfect" as per this rule you realize which is good or best. One more thing keep habit like after done your work just ask third person who don't know any idea about your current work. And take review from him/her. Your work flow is understandable or not. Easily understandable or need to think more. And you can get idea.